# Raise events from C to C# (iOS to Unity)

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I would like to register for events in Unity and raise those events from C in iOS.

I have the following pattern -

```
// Unity side register delegate and event handler
private delegate void CallbackDelegate(CBObj data);
public static event CallbackDelegate dataUpdatedEvent;

// for iOS
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_IOS
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void PluginFunction(CallbackDelegate callback);
#endif

public CBObj {
    // marshal C objects to c# objects in the constructor here using the Ptr from C
}
[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(CallbackDelegate))]
static void CallbackMethod(CBObj dataPtr)
{
    if (dataUpdatedEvent != null)
    {
        CBObj obj = new CBObj(dataPtr);
        dataUpdatedEvent(obj);
    }
}

// Unity Usage
private CallbackDelegate evt;
void Start(){
    evt += updateEvent;
}
public void updateEvent(CBObj data){
    // do something with data everytime its called
}

// C code
extern "C" typedef void (*CallBackFuncP) (CBObj dataPtr);
typedef struct
{
    float *data1;
    int *data2;
} CBObj;
extern "C" {
    CallBackFuncP* cb;
    void PluginFunction(CallBackFuncP callback) {
        // store the the callback function pointer
        cb = callback;
    }
}
// raise the event somewhere in code
if (cb != NULL) {
    CBObj *test =  [[CBObj alloc] init];
    cb(test)
}
```

Would this work? Is this the correct pattern? Is there a better way to do it?

Any pointers to do this are highly appreciated.

Comment: In your managed code, what is `CBObj`? A class or a struct?

Comment: I managed to solve most of the issue btw. Will post an update to the code. To answer your question - it is a c# class. I am stuck at one last operation here - CBObj obj = new CBObj(dataPtr); constructs the object properly, but I have to change delegate definition to public delegate void CallbackDelegate(IntPtr dataPtr); since the ptr comes through from ios and when I call DataUpdatedEvent(obj); it complains that it cannot convert from iOS.CBObj to IntPtr. Any pointers to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by the following patter and it worked flawlessly. Hope this helps someone.

```
// Unity side register delegate and event handler
delegate void Internal_CallbackDelegate(IntPtr dataPtr);
public delegate void CallbackDelegate(CBObj data);
// The above pattern is to deal with pointer conversion from iOS to Unity
public static event CallbackDelegate DataUpdatedEvent;

// YourUnityKlass for iOS 
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_IOS
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void PluginFunction(Internal_CallbackDelegate callback);
#endif
// Where this class is declared call in constructor
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_IOS
    PluginFunction(CallbackMethod);
#endif

public CBObj {
    // marshal C objects to c# objects in the constructor here using the Ptr from C
    private IntPtr m_Ptr;
    internal CBObj(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ArgumentException("ptr may not be IntPtr.Zero");
        m_Ptr = ptr;
        // getDataFromC();
    }
    // get individual pointers by exposing them via C and mashall copy the data as per your needs 
}

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Internal_CallbackDelegate))]
static void CallbackMethod(IntPtr dataPtr)
{
    if (DataUpdatedEvent != null)
    {
        CBObj obj = new CBObj(dataPtr);
        DataUpdatedEvent(obj);
    }
}

// Unity Usage
void Start(){
    YourUnityKlass klass  = new YourUnityKlass();
    YourUnityKlass.DataUpdatedEvent += updateEvent;
}
public void updateEvent(CBObj data){
    // do something with data every time its called
}

// C header - code
typedef struct
{
    float *data1;
    int *data2;
} CBObj;
typedef void (*CallBackFuncP) (CBObj* dataPtr);
@interface CallbackWrapper : NSObject
{
@public
    CallBackFuncP _dataUpdate;
}
- (void) sendDataUpdate:(CBObj*) obj;
@end

// C - impl code
@implementation CallbackWrapper
-(void) sendDataUpdate:(CBObj*) objPtr
{
    if (_dataUpdate != NULL){
        _dataUpdate(objPtr);
    }
}
@end
extern "C" {
    void PluginFunction(CallBackFuncP callback) {
        // Create a swiftKlass to store your callback pointer
        CallbackWrapper* cb = [[SwiftKlass shared] getCallback];
        cb->_dataUpdate = callback;
    }
}
// Swift usage - Inside say SwiftKlass
@objc public func getCallback() -> CallbackWrapper {
    return self.cb
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unity suggests using [UnitySendMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html) function to call a C# method from C.

You can use json to format the data

```
NSDictionary *d = @{ @"data1":1, @"data2":2.0 };
NSData *j = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName", "MethodName", [s UTF8String]);
```

In unity, create a GameObject named **GameObjectName**, attach a script with a method named **MethodName**. Use a [json library](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) to decode the string into an object.

```
public class YourScriptName : Monobehaviour
{
    public class CBObj
    {
        public int data1;
        public float data2;
    }

    public void MethodName(string data)
    {
         var obj = UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson<CBObj>(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes you have access to "UnityAppController.h" . I got into all kinds of trouble and also you have a delay of 1 frame as per the documentation. I posted an answer on the method I used. It is super performant and solved my issue.